# Санта-Клаус или Санта Клаус?

Tags: орфография

Встречаю в текстах оба варианта написания. А как все-таки правильно, когда речь идет о "кока-кольном" старике?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари, правда, дают лишь один вариант: Санта-Клаус, но мне кажется, тут есть о чем порассуждать. Сравните с Дедом Морозом. Если речь идет о самом мифологическом существе, то Дед Мороз. Если о фигурке, которую под ёлку ставят, то дед-мороз. Во всяком случае такая рекомендация была лет тридцать назад. Отсюда, видимо, желание писать "Санта Клаус" в случаях, когда речь идет о самом Санте, а не о его уличном воплощении.

Но меня крепко насторожила ваша фраза насчет "кока-кольного" старика. Почему "кока-кольный" и о каких еще Сантах может идти речь? Ни прообраз его, Святого Николая, ни вообще святых, никто никогда Сантой не называл в русской традиции.

//--------  *Fuchoin Kazuki*

У вас формулировка как минимум не совсем точная. 
"Не имеет никакого отношения" - это заведомо противоречит тому, что сказано далее. Можно говорить о том, что *образ* Санты не имеет отношения к св. Николаю Мирликийскому (в русской традиции - Николай Угодник, Николай Чудотворец), об этом ниже, но никак не сам Санта, ибо это голландская "транскрипция" имени именно этого святого (несколько искажена, точнее: Синтер Клаас).

Теперь по сути. Я два года жил в Голландии и лично видел картинки Санты, сделанные едва ли не за несколько веков до американского Томаса. Они мало отличаются от современных. Американцы просто слямзили этот образ. Что отличается, так это то, что в Голландии Санта ходит 5 декабря, а вместо Снегурочки у него симпатичный негритенок лет пяти. Если посмотреть жизнеописания св. Николая, то аллегория станет понятна. Американцы парня просто выкинули. По причине неполиткорректности, не иначе. Правда, на более древних рисунках "негритенку" лет тридцать. И это уже прямой намек на одного из реальных "спутников жизни" св. Николая, Петера (его смешивали со св. Петром Александрийским, но это ошибочно, "наш" чернокожий Петер канонизирован не был).

Вот, кстати, более или менее адекватная (моим представлениям) история, пусть и не в самом авторитетном изложении.
http://www.ladyfromrussia.com/karnaval/pr/chr_snt.shtml

Теперь насчет Деда Мороза. Я не нашел убедительных доказательств того, что "нашенский" дед был массово известен ранее 30-х годов XX века, когда Советское правительство озаботилось тем, чем де все-таки заменить идеологически вредные рождественские елки. Нашли какого-то всеми забытого "фольклорного элемента" с довольно мерзким характером: исторически он занимался тем, что зимой сбивал с дороги припозднившихся пуnников и морозил заплутавших. Надели на него голубую шубу, состарили изрядно, приклеили бороду - получите доброго дедушку. Причем все в нем, за исключением цвета шубы, весьма и весьма напоминает именно Санту. А сейчас и последнее различие пропало. Так что я совсем не разделяю всех этих терок насчет истинной национальности нашенского деда.

Comment: Вообще-то, американский Санта-Клаус не имеет никакого отношения к святому Николаю Угоднику. Его образ был разработан Томасом Нэстом исключительно для рекламы Кока-колы еще в начале ХХ века. Использовать в рекламе детей было нельзя, а им нужно было как-то продвигать эту отраву детям, плюс — зимой.  
Так что меня, например, просто бесит, когда им подменяют нашего Деда Мороза, а насчет Николая Чудотворца — это просто настоящее кощунство!

Comment: Ответил у тексте.

Comment: Не знаю-не знаю. Классически Дед Мороз был в красной шубе, а Снегурка - в синей. Или это все-таки под влияем запада такую одежду им придумали? Ну, и Санта Клаус все-таки в полушубке, а не в шубе до пола...